# lengthMenu option not working in DataTable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app that is currently working and I would like to add the lenghtMenu option in the datatable. It seems it is  not working.  I am not so sure if I place it in the wrong place in the R code. Thank you for looking into this.

Here is my code:

```
output$sbirx.view <- DT::renderDataTable(
{
  input$submit1 
  if (input$submit1==0) return()
  isolate({
    datatable(dataset.filter(), 
              rownames=FALSE,
              extensions = c("FixedColumns", "FixedHeader", "Scroller"), 
              options = list(searching=TRUE,
                            autoWidth=TRUE,
                            scroller=TRUE,
                            scrollX=TRUE,
                            #scrollY="500px",
                          scrollY=paste0(factor*nrow(dataset.filter()),"px"),
                            fixedHeader=TRUE,
                            class='cell-border stripe',
                            lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 5,

 fixedColumns=list(leftColumns=2,heightMatch='none')
                            )
           )
  })

 })
```

Comment: looks to me like the combination of scroller and lengthMenu. Why would you use both together? "Scroller is a virtual rendering plug-in for DataTables which allows large datasets to be drawn on screen very quickly." Do you have a large dataset to be drawn quickly or do you want to limit the view to 5/30/50 obs? If you remove the scroller parameter it should work fine,...

Comment: Thank you for looking into. Yes, I do have a large dataset which I want to limit the view as well to scroll the screen vertically and horizontally.  If I have a smaller set of observations, there is a lot of space at the bottom   of the screen because I defined my scrollY="500px". Is there an automatic way to display the screen depending on the number of observations? Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: well of course you can make your options dynamic. E.g. set `scrollY=paste0(factor*nrow(dataset.filter()),"px") and choose `factor` accordingly. But again are you sure you need both `scroller` and the `lengthMenu` ?

Comment: If I could adjust the display then I don't need to use the lengthMenu. I do apologise since I am new to R and shiny. Do I replace my current code of

Comment: scrollY="500px" to your code. I do apologise since I am new to R and shiny. Where do I choose the factor? Can you please show it to my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments this might help you:
The factor you have to choose according to your needs i guess.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             dataTableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDataTable(iris,
                                    rownames=FALSE,
                                    extensions = c("FixedColumns", "FixedHeader", "Scroller"), 
                                    options = list(searching=TRUE,
                                                   # autoWidth=TRUE,
                                                   scroller=TRUE,
                                                   scrollX=TRUE,
                                                   scrollY=paste0(4*nrow(iris),"px"),
                                                   fixedHeader=TRUE,
                                                   class='cell-border stripe',
                                                   fixedColumns=list(leftColumns=2,heightMatch='none')
                                    )
    )
  }
)
```